# Differential equation from a circuit: two methods give different results

Tags: circuit-analysis, laplace-transform

I saw an example problem from a lecture note and tried to solve it by a different method. Then I got confused as the results are different. 
Here is the example:
It's not some web site as I know so I'll capture to show here:

[image]

**And solution from the lecture:**

[image]

[image]

**My attempt:**
I called the middle node in Laplace is `Vc` and tried to solve it with Laplace and then convert it to differential equation instead.

[image]

From here I think it's straightforward to convert it to differential equation with `Vc(t)` but I got confused as the two are not same. You can see that in my Lapalce equation there is a term `-E*L` which is `-44` there is not present in the solution in the lecture note.

I have been trying to check for several hours but couldn't find the error. 
 Hope someone can help.

Comment: Replace E/s with E and you will get your answer. Your equation is dimensionally incorrect, that should be your first check.

Comment: @sarthak how would you know that E is constant all the time not just unit step? I don't think it's wrong dimensionally? I did try to solve it as well and match with simulation.

Comment: I know because it is a **constant** voltage source. If you want a step, add a switch after the source. But even if it is a step E-V/s is incorrect. You need to solve it separately before and after the switch closes.

Comment: @sarthak do you mean E/s - V not E- V/s? I wondered how it could be wrong as I have solved lot of problems with Laplace transform and got them correct. I know the initial condition and then add it to the model but they're all zero here.

Comment: To be sure, always check with a simulator ... and think logical to recheck ... if E was a constant, nothing should happens because you should be in 'steady state' conditions !

Comment: It's always great to check a good simulator with ideal parts then with experience add on the non-ideal RLC parasitic.  https://tinyurl.com/2kx6gf2r  rev A https://tinyurl.com/2k6wl43x

Comment: The OP made the following edit/update after answers had been written based on the original version of the question. As it significantly changed the premise of the question and affected existing answers, that edit has been rolled-back per standard policy. However in order to capture the explanation by the OP in that late edit, rather than just deleting it, here it is (see the following 2 comments):

Comment: *(Edit made to the question by the OP - Dec 14 at 10:25, part 1 of 2)* When I did my derivation above, that `E` there should have written as `E0` instead, where `E=E0*u(t)`. The Laplace transform of it would be `E(s)=E0/s`. I can see now that why you all are confused. However, I actually did that correctly as I knew what I was doing so for me that is not a problem. It would be wrong if I substituted `E` with `11/s` but no assigned `E` as magnitude so `E=11` instead.

Comment: *(Edit made to the question by the OP - Dec 14 at 10:25, part 2 of 2)* Probably I should have told that from beginning or I should have been more careful when I do posting online. I don't have any problem solve that but just confusion from my notation. It's good that you showed that confusion as well. However, if you just want to insist that I was wrong then that is good too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two results don't correspond because there are two different functions being used for \$E\$. In time-domain approach taken in the lecture, it is assumed that \$E\$ is constant for all \$t\$, whereas in your Laplace solution, \$E\$ is assumed to be a step function.

The assumption of constant \$E\$ (for all time) is applied in the lecture between Equation 6 and Equation 7 when the derivative of \$i_L(t)\$ is computed, and \$dE/dt\$ is assumed to be zero. The final differential equation arrived at is true if \$E(t)\$ is taken as a constant for all \$t\$ (including \$t\leq 0\$). If you want to an equation that is valid for something more general, we must not assume \$dE/dt=0\$ for all \$t\$.

Pursuing this path and leaving the voltage \$E\$ to be a general function of time \$E(t)\$, we can start from Equation 6 in the lecture. Equation 7 then becomes

$$
\frac{di_L(t)}{dt}=\frac{1}{R_1}E’(t) - \frac{1}{R_1}\frac{du_c(t)}{dt} – C\frac{d^2u_c(t)}{dt^2}
$$

If you now want to solve the same problem as you are setting up with your Laplace version of the solution, you have to keep this \$E’(t)\$ term. If \$E(t)\$ is the step function multiplied by 11, then the derivative  is \$E’(t) = 11\delta(t)\$.

Following through with the substitution of the above equation in place of Equation 7, you discover an extra term appears on the right-hand side of the differential equal to \$660\delta(t)\$, which is exactly the term that [@aconcernedcitizen](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/646078/250420) pointed out is required to make the solutions match.

**[edit]**

An interesting question that comes up from [@aconcernedcitizen](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/646078/250420) calculations is how to get the correct answer from the time-domain approach taken in the lecture, using the assumption that the applied voltage \$E\$ is in fact a constant for all \$t\$, (including at \$t\leq 0\$), rather than a step function. We should be able to approach it this way if we put a switch into the right place. If this assumption is made, the differential equation given in the lecture is actually correct. Even the \$h(t)\$ given in @aconcernedcitizen ’s answer (Equation 3 from that post) satisfies the differential equation for all \$t\geq  0\$.

If you set up the problem an assume \$E\$ is in fact a constant, and we want to solve the same physical problem that the OP solved with the Laplace Transform, then we need to insert a switch in series with the voltage source to apply it at \$t=0\$ to the rest of the circuit. When this switch is closed at \$t=0\$, we can solve the differential equation given in the lecture and get the correct answer, but we need to get the initial conditions right.

The key is that the initial conditions for this approach are not the same as the zero-inititial conditions used in the approach in which the voltage source is applied as a step function. For this approach to work, the initial conditions are

\$(1) u_c(t=0) = 0  \$

\$(2) \frac{du_c}{dt}|_{t=0} = \frac{i_c(t=0)}{C} = \frac{E}{R_1C}\$

The first condition says that there is no initial voltage on the capacitor. The second condition is simply saying that the initial current into the capacitor when the switch is closed is \$E/R_1\$, which is true because of the first condition and because the initial condition on the inductor current is \$i_L=0\$. Note the \$E\$ here is just a constant, not a function.

If you solve the second-order inhomogeneous differential equation given in the lecture with these initial conditions, you get the correct answer given in Equation 3 of [@aconcernedcitizen](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/646078/250420) 's answer. This is not how such problems are typically solved in electrical engineering, but is a valid approach.

Comment: If  `E` is always consant for both negative and positive time, would that mean we don't have any differential equation at all as everything is in stead state with `Vc = E*R2/(R1+R2)`?

Comment: No, it would not mean that. Remember that the differential equation is just a relationship between the derivatives of a function and tells us how the system will evolve. To find an actual solution, we must start the system in an initial state and then solve the equation. So we could set up initial currents or voltages with other elements, then toggle some switches that removes those elements and leaves us with this circuit, and solve for the time evolution from that point forward using the differential equation.

Answer (score 1):

The textbook seems to be wrong. If you solve their equation with initial conditions zero for all, you get a different answer than the correct one, which is different than yours.

First, to check the textbook, I used both LTspice and wxMaxima with these:

```
atvalue('diff(vc(t), t, 2), t=0, 0)$
atvalue('diff(vc(t), t), t=0, 0)$
atvalue(vc(t), t=0, 0)$
desolve(16*'diff(vc(t), t, 2) + 72*'diff(vc(t), t) + 65*vc(t) = 495, vc(t));
plot2d(rhs(%), [t, 0, 10])$
```

If the code looks a bit hard to digest, I'm solving their final differential equation. The result and plots are these:

$$v_c(t)=-\dfrac{99}{8}\exp\left(-\dfrac{5}{4}t\right)+\dfrac{495}{104}\exp\left(-\dfrac{13}{4}t\right)+\dfrac{99}{13} \tag{1}$$

[image: LTspice vs textbook]

The two results differ quite a lot but, between their handwritten solution and LTspice, I trust the latter. So then I solved it based on your Laplace initial equation, leading to the following transfer function:

$$H(s)=\dfrac{660s+495}{16s^3+72s^2+65s} \tag{2}$$

If you now apply the inverse Laplace you get the time response. First apply partial fraction decomposition because the roots are simple and nice and round:

$$\begin{align}
H(s)&=\dfrac{33}{4s+5}-\dfrac{825}{13(4s+13)}+\dfrac{99}{13s} \\
h(t)&=\dfrac{33}{4}\exp\left(-\dfrac{5}{4}t\right)-\dfrac{825}{52}\exp\left(-\dfrac{13}{4}t\right)+\dfrac{99}{13} \tag{3}
\end{align}$$

Sure enough, plotting (3) shows this, which is exactly what `B1` shows in the picture above (same formula, just slightly shifted otherwise it would completely overlap):

[image: correct result]

And then, if you perform this tiny modification to their differential equation -- adding \$660\delta(t)\$ to the right hand side -- then the solution comes out pristine:

```
desolve(16*'diff(vc(t), t, 2) + 72*'diff(vc(t), t) + 65*vc(t) = 660*delta(t) + 495, vc(t));

                                   5 t           13 t
                                 - ---         - ----
                                    4             4
                            33 %e        825 %e         99
(%o7)               vc(t) = ---------- - ------------ + --
                                4             52        13
```

Guess why?

---

[edit]

It was late and I stopped after hinting about the mistake. Very soon after (while I was correcting), [@rpm2718's answer came](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/646081/95619). At any rate, I'll continue my thoughts as they were.

Your first two steps in solving the problem are correct (except the way you wrote the input source), until you try to line them all up in an equation similar to a differential -- that's where the mistakes are.

First, you wrote \$E/s\$ as the input -- this is not correct. \$E\$ is the source and \$E=11/s\$, so \$E/s=11/s^2\$; you are integrating an already integrated impulse response (you get a ramp). Then, when you tried to get rid of fractions, you mingled this information: the \$s\$ that belongs to \$E\$ is part of the *input* but, when you used that \$s\$ to factor out terms, you mixed it with the other \$s\$ terms that belong to the output.

What you should have done was, when you've dealt with Laplace, obtain the transfer function, don't expand it as if it's an equation in time domain. By obtaining the transfer function you clearly separate the input (numerator) to the output (denominator). Therefore, your first two steps should have looked like this:

$$\begin{align}
&\dfrac{V_C-E}{R_1}+V_CsC+\dfrac{V_C}{R_2+sL}=0 \\
\Rightarrow\quad &{V_C}=\dfrac{E(60s+45)}{16s^2+72s+65} \tag{4}
\end{align}$$

Now you can expand (4) to look like this:

$$\begin{align}
16s^2+72s+65&=E(60s+45) \\
16s^2+72s+65&=60s\cdot \dfrac{11}{s}+45\cdot \dfrac{11}{s} \tag{5}
\end{align}$$

You could simplify the \$s\$ on the right side, if you wanted but, if your aim is to convert (5) into its time domain equivalent then you have to consider that \$11/s\$ as standalone, and that's because the source translates to the Heaviside function:

$$\dfrac{11}{s}\rightarrow 11\theta(t) \tag{6}$$

This is important: it tells you that, since the whole analysis is done from \$t=0...\infty\$, the Heaviside reduces to unity, leaving the right side as \$60\cdot 11\delta(t)+45\cdot 11\$, multiplied by the amplitude of (6), \$11\$. And that's how you reach the equation at the end of my initial edit.

As for the textbook, they got the differentiation of \$i_L(t)\$ wrong in their step #7 (and, implicitly, a sign). This is how it should have been:

$$\begin{align}
E&=\theta(t) \\
E'&=\delta(t) \\
i_L&=\dfrac{11\theta-u_C}{R_1}-Cu_C' \\
i_L'&=\dfrac{11\delta-u_C'}{R1}-Cu_C'' \tag{7}
\end{align}$$

Now the substitution of #6 and #7 in #3 results in:

$$\begin{align}
&R_2\left(\dfrac{11\theta-u_C}{R_1}-Cu_C'\right)+L\left(\dfrac{11\delta-u_C'}{R_1}-Cu_C''\right)-u_C=0 \\
\Rightarrow \\
&\dfrac{660\delta+495\theta-16u_C''-72u_C'-65u_C}{20}=0 \\
\Rightarrow \\
&660\delta+495\theta=16u_C''+72u_C'+65u_C \tag{7}
\end{align}$$

And this, again, is the equation in my last edit, where \$495\theta\$ reduces to \$495\$ because we're dealing with \$t>=0\$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141362/discussion-on-answer-by-a-concerned-citizen-differential-equation-from-a-circuit).

Answer (score 0):

Well, using Laplace we can see that:

$$\text{V}_\text{C}\left(t\right)=\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\underbrace{\frac{1}{\text{sC}}}_\text{impedance capacitor}\cdot\underbrace{\frac{\frac{\hat{\text{u}}_{\space\text{i}}}{\text{s}}}{\text{R}_1+\left(\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\space\text{||}\space\left(\text{R}_2+\text{sL}\right)\right)}}_\text{input current}\cdot\underbrace{\frac{\text{R}_2+\text{sL}}{\text{R}_2+\text{sL}+\frac{1}{\text{sC}}}}_\text{current divider}\right]_{\left(t\right)}\tag1$$

Where \$\alpha\space\text{||}\space\beta:=\frac{\alpha\beta}{\alpha+\beta}\$.

Comment: Hi, I don't think you give any thing new here. I used nodal analysis to solve for Vc above and you applied the normal way with current divider. So the result should be same as what I gave above. I do know how to solve for Vc(s) and invert Laplace to Vc(t). However, my confusion is why they don't match as I shown in my post above.