# What is the correct way of replacing the value of a step voltage source in Laplace?

Tags: circuit-analysis, laplace-transform, step-response

I'll be presenting two ways to reach the same answer. I would like to hear which way is the correct way to get there. I am not interested in the result, it's the same in both cases, I'm interested in the methods, themselves. The more answers, the better (for the sake of a majority).

Consider the basic circuit below where the output voltage is needed:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYyXO0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

**1st method:**

$$\begin{align}
V_{out}\left(sC+\dfrac1R\right)&=\dfrac{E}{R} \tag{1a} \\
V_{out}&=\dfrac{\dfrac{E}{s}}{R\left(sC+\dfrac1R\right)} \tag{2a} \\
{}&=\dfrac{\dfrac{E}{s}}{RCs+1} \tag{3a} \\
\mathcal{L}^{-1}(V_{out})&=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\dfrac1s}{1\cdot 1\cdot s+1}\right) \tag{4a} \\
{}&=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\dfrac{1}{s(s+1)}\right) \tag{5a} \\
\Rightarrow\quad y(t)&=1-\mathrm{e}^{-t} \tag{6a}
\end{align}$$

What I did: in (1a) there are the node equations, where I used \$E\$ <sup>[note#1]</sup> to denote the input source (unity Heaviside). In (2a) and (3a) I obtain the transfer function by replacing \$E=\frac{E}{s}\$. In (4a) and (5a) I apply the inverse Laplace by replacing the values for \$E=1\$, \$R=1\$, and \$C=1\$. In (6a) I get the correct result.

---

**2nd method:**

$$\begin{align}
V_{out}\left(sC+\dfrac1R\right)&=\dfrac{E}{R} \tag{1b} \\
V_{out}&=\dfrac{E}{R\left(sC+\dfrac1R\right)} \tag{2b} \\
{}&=\dfrac{E}{RCs+1} \tag{3b} \\
\mathcal{L}^{-1}(V_{out})&=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\dfrac1s}{1\cdot 1\cdot s+1}\right) \tag{4b} \\
{}&=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\dfrac{1}{s(s+1)}\right) \tag{5b} \\
\Rightarrow\quad y(t)&=1-\mathrm{e}^{-t} \tag{6b}
\end{align}$$

(1a) and (1b) are identical. In (2b) and (3b) I obtain the transfer function by keeping the input source as \$E\$. In (4b) and (5b) I substitute the values as \$E=\frac1s\$, \$R=1\$, and \$C=1\$. (6b) is identical with (6a).

---

Which ones are correct and why (simple yes/no are not enough):

1. Replacing \$E=\frac{E}{s}\$ in (1a) → (2a), or keeping \$E=E\$ in (1b) → (2b).
2. Substituting the value of \$\frac{E}{s}=\frac1s\$ in (3a) → (4a), or \$E=\frac1s\$ in (3b) → (4b).

---

I don't intend to answer this question and I am interested in clear arguments for why or why not. This is as a result from a very divergent discussion that happened [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/645472/95619), where I argued that the second part is the correct part, and the only reason why the results match is due to a fortunate cancelling of mistakes -- because, if the value substitutions would not be performed, the result will be wrong since \$\frac{E}{s}=\frac{1}{s^2}\$.

---

<sub>[note#1]: technically it should be \$E(s)\$ and \$V_{out}(s)\$ but, here I kept it as it is for the sake of similarity with [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/645472/95619), which is where the problem orriginates from.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

The applied voltage is improperly designated (formulated) in both the circuit diagram and the text. On the circuit diagram labeling the source as \$E(s)\$ or  \$\frac{E}{s}\$ would be better.

In the text, "\$E(s)=\frac{E}{s}\$ where \$E\$ is a constant." has better clarity.

Although, I prefer, "\$E(s)=\frac{E_{A}}{s}\$ where \$E_{A}\$ is the step height."

> 1. Replacing \$E=\frac{E}{s}\$ in (1a) → (2a), ...

In the first place: \$E \ne \frac{E}{s}\$. Secondly, Laplace functions are symbolized in uppercase as are constants. So to tell them apart, proper notation must be used as you suggested in Note 1:

> ...technically it should be \$E(s)\$ and \$V_{out}(s)\$ but...

Also, \$E(s) \ne \frac{E(s)}{s}\$. However \$E(s) = \frac{E}{s}\$ can be considered valid where the first \$E\$ is designated as a Laplace function. The second \$E\$ is designated as a constant. More clarity can be provided by subscripting the constant.

> ...or keeping \$E=E\$ in (1b) → (2b)...

In this case, \$E\$ should be interpreted as a constant. Mathematically (1b) → (2b) is correct, but there is still ambiguity as to the meaning of \$E\$.

> 2. Substituting the value of \$\frac{E}{s}=\frac1s\$ in (3a) → (4a),...

The substitution indicates that \$E\$ is a constant. Until this point, the meaning of \$E\$ is still ambiguous. The meaning of \$E\$ should be clear at the start not somewhere in the middle.

> 2. ...or \$E=\frac1s\$ in (3b) → (4b).

Continuing the same theme, the reader again must imagine what the author means. Is \$E\$ a constant or a function?

========================================================

**Method 1 (my way)**
$$\begin{align}
E(s):=\frac{E_{A}}{s}\\
V_{out}\left(sC+\dfrac1R\right)&=\dfrac{E(s)}{R} \tag{1a} \\
V_{out}&=\dfrac{\dfrac{E_{A}}{s}}{R\left(sC+\dfrac1R\right)} \tag{2a} \\
{}&=\dfrac{\dfrac{E_{A}}{s}}{RCs+1} \tag{3a} \\
\mathcal{L}^{-1}(V_{out})&=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\dfrac1s}{1\cdot 1\cdot s+1}\right); E_{A}=1 \tag{4a} \\
{}&=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\dfrac{1}{s(s+1)}\right) \tag{5a} \\
\Rightarrow\quad y(t)&=1-\mathrm{e}^{-t} \tag{6a}
\end{align}$$

====================================================

**Method 2 (my way)**

$$\begin{align}
E(s):=\frac{E_{A}}{s}\\
V_{out}\left(sC+\dfrac1R\right)&=\dfrac{E(s)}{R} \tag{1b} \\
V_{out}&=\dfrac{E(s)}{R\left(sC+\dfrac1R\right)} \tag{2b} \\
{}&=\dfrac{E(s)}{RCs+1} \tag{3b} \\
\mathcal{L}^{-1}(V_{out})&=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\dfrac1s}{1\cdot 1\cdot s+1}\right) ; E_{A}=1\tag{4b} \\
{}&=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\dfrac{1}{s(s+1)}\right) \tag{5b} \\
\Rightarrow\quad y(t)&=1-\mathrm{e}^{-t} \tag{6b}
\end{align}$$

================================

**My answer**

Neither method described in the OP are correct. Both are ambiguous in their presentation.

Both methods presented my way are clear and correct.

Comment: Yes, it's more clear and also conformant with my 2nd method, which was meant to have E(s) as per the note, and which is what I tried to say with E=E, above. I know I should have left E(s) but, I kept it that way because that's how the linked answer has it written (so for the sake of similarity). But, the other problem is with the value replacement: E/s=1/s. This fails even with the ambiguity E=E(s) cleared: if it's E(s)/s it's wrong (integrated step = ramp), if E is a value then E/s=1/s => that E=1, which is, again, wrong, since it's a step and the source, itself is E. And that was my point.

Comment: `Although, I prefer, "E(s)=EAsE(s)=EAs where EAEA is the step height."` this is what I have been told him. At first, it was confusing which is true. But then I told him that my `E` there was `EA` in your formula or `Eo` in my post there but he just cannot accept that and just wanted me to accept that I don't know how to solve it. It was just my presentation which I should have been writing EA instead of E there. If you check the edit section of my post there or the comments which I have been telling him a lot before.

Comment: @internet You only said that *after* I told you (and not only) that your notation is wrong. The edit in your question only came *after* that and the comments. Even so, the (other) point is that it doesn't matter what you *think* you're doing, what matters is what you've shown, and all the answers and comments were related to *that*. Apparently you didn't like people pointing out the mistake and you resorted to ad hominem. And now I see an upvote on your comment and makes me wonder if, whomever did that, even bothered to read the linked question.

Comment: BTW, if you look closely, this answer only agrees with mine if you take into account the note in the OP. Which, again, makes me wonder about the upvote in your comment.

Comment: @all: Folks, I am not taking sides here. This is what I stated as my answer. "Neither method described in the OP are correct. Both are ambiguous in their presentation." Please take your discussion elsewhere.

Comment: `You only said that after I told you (and not only) that your notation is wrong. The edit in your question only came after that and the comments.`  This is true and I never said otherwise. As I always think of my `E` as the magnitude `EA` in RussellH's answer so I didn't know why you all confused. However, after that I realized the confusion because of the notation, I did admit that and explained to you all that my `E` there is actually meant to be magnitude `EA` or `Eo`. However, no matter what I have been saying, you just don't want to accept that.

Comment: My comment was some days ago and not just after the answer. I don't know why it is hard for you to accept that. I did say clearly that my `E` is actually magnitude `EA` in the comments but you  just won't accept that.

Comment: I would be perfectly normal for you to said that in my original post as it is actually confusing. However, you keep saying that and won't accept even when I have been explaining to you a lot that my `E` there is magnitude `EA` or `Eo` in my notation there. You keep saying that I made two mistakes in a row that make it correct while I did explain to you all the time there.

Comment: Here is the proof. I did say that 5 days ago and you kept ignoring that and don't just want to accept. 
https://ibb.co/Gpr8HvL